# Using a DataTrigger in my Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I am trying to change the fill of a rectangle based upon a value in my ViewModel but despite having tried all the suggestions I have found online, it still isn't working.

The IsMouseOver trigger works fine but the DataTrigger is ignored despite the fact there is always either a 4 or 5 in my ViewModel property.

Could somebody show me where I may be going wrong?

Thanks.

This is my style:

```
        <Style x:Key="FavouriteRectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        <Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            </Trigger>


            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Theme}" Value="4">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="{DynamicResource content__star__hex646464__shadow}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Theme}" Value="5">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="{DynamicResource content__star__favorit__hexebebeb__shadow}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

EDIT: So it seems that my Binding was incorrect due to my incorrect assumption that the DataContext of the UserControl is where I should direct the binding.

The Rectangle is in the template for a ListBox and has "Items" as it's DataContext so by changing the "Binding" it now works.

Many thanks for all assistance though:

SOLUTION:

```
<Style x:Key="FavouriteRectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        <Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            </Trigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Theme,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                               AncestorType=UserControl} }" Value="4">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" 
                                    Value="{DynamicResource content__star__hex646464__shadow}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Theme,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                               AncestorType=UserControl} }" Value="5">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" 
                          Value="{DynamicResource content__star__favorit__hexebebeb__shadow}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you kindly post the XAML regarding the rectangle which you apply the `FavouriteRectangleStyle` to?

Comment: this <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="0.5" /> should be this <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" /> and all of them should be similar you dont need Rectangle. because your style targets rectangle.

Comment: Does your `<Rectangle>` tag contain the `Fill` property? Properties defined directly in the Tag, like `<Rectangle Fill="White">`, will always take precedence over triggered values in the Style, so the values from your data trigger will never get applied. The solution is to define the default Fill property in the style itself instead of in the tag. For example, `<Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />`

Comment: My Rectangle XAML is as follows:
               <Rectangle Width="16"
                   Height="16"
                   Margin="3,0,10,0" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource FavouriteRectangleStyle}">
               </Rectangle>

If I remove the "Rectangle." part from the Setter Property, the IsMousOver trigger doesn't work at all.

Comment: I should add that this Rectangle is being used within a ListBox and the ItemsSource is a property of the DataContext of the parent control and "Theme" is a property of the parent control's DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `TargetType="Rectangle"`

Here is the code I used to test

```
 <Style x:Key="FavouriteRectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>           
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>           
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            </Trigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Theme}" Value="4">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>                  
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Theme}" Value="5">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger> 

        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the implementation

```
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource FavouriteRectangleStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this initially but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the constructor of your window or usercontrol what you haveused, you should set    this.DataContext = this; Otherwise binding not properly worked for the corresponding window or usercontrol.

Comment: My DataContext is working fine. I am using this rectangle in a ListBox.ItemTemplate and the ItemsSource for the ListBox is from the same DataContext and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

That probably because you miss to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, update you Theme property to this:

```
 private int _theme = 5;
    public int Theme
    {
        get
        {
            return _theme;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_theme == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _theme = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
```

and make sure your codebehind or your viewmodel is implementing the interface

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
```

here a full working sample:

```
 Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="content__star__hex646464__shadow" Color="Red"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="content__star__favorit__hexebebeb__shadow" Color="Green"/>
    <Style x:Key="FavouriteRectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        <Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            </Trigger>


            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Theme}" Value="4">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="{DynamicResource content__star__hex646464__shadow}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Theme}" Value="5">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="{DynamicResource content__star__favorit__hexebebeb__shadow}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource FavouriteRectangleStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="100"></Rectangle>
    <Button Content="Change Theme" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

and the code behind :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int _theme = 5;
    public int Theme
    {
        get
        {
            return _theme;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_theme == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _theme = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


    }
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Theme = Theme == 5 ? 4 : 5;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi, I checked my DataContext and ViewModel and with regard to the DataContext, everything is working fine. This problem is within a ListBox but the ItemsSource for the ListBox is from the same DataContext.

I'm using the same OnPropertyChanged() approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in EDIT part of original question. Thanks for all assistance